# Cake 2.X How to refresh session at each action

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a way in CakePhp 2.X where at each beginning of a page my user's session is refreshed with the data in the database ?

For the moment, i could only make it work if the user is inside the **UsersController :**

```
public function beforeRender($user = null){
    parent::beforeRender($user);
    if(AuthComponent::user()){
        $info = $this->User->findById( $this->Auth->User('id'));
        $this->Auth->login( $info['User']);
    }
}
```

But i have no clue on how to automate this action through the whole site since the User object only exists in my UsersController.

I'm new to cakePhp so sorry if i miss some concepts.

Comment: remove it fro m all controllers and put this function in `AppController` and then check. Also in each controller check that `Auth component` is added

Comment: It gives me a fatal error : Fatal error: Call to a member function findById() on null in C:\..\app\Controller\AppController.php on line 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the logic to the `beforeRender` callback of your `AppController` and remember to make sure that you've loaded the `User` model that you want to query:-

```
public function beforeRender() {
    parent::beforeRender();
    if (AuthComponent::user()) {
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $info = $this->User->findById( $this->Auth->User('id'));
        $this->Auth->login($info['User']);
    }
}
```

Also note that the `beforeRender` method takes no parameters.

Comment: Oke ! Now i understand the loadModel() ! Thank you

Comment: @user3089871 no problem, you might find this blog post useful: http://andy-carter.com/blog/loading-cakephp-models-inside-other-models-and-controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd move this function to the AppController (which all controllers should inherit from), this would then fire on every page lifecycle

Comment: It gives me a fatal error : Fatal error: Call to a member function findById() on null in C:\..\app\Controller\AppController.php on line 70